# Add PHP variable To SQL Value Using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I add a PHP variable's value to a value in my database? I'm forced to use PDO, so this is what I have so far and it works just fine to add 20 to reputation;

```
$rep = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `reputation` = `reputation` + 20 WHERE `email` = :email");
$rep->bindParam(":email", $_SESSION['email']);
$rep->execute();
```

Now, I wan't to add a variable called $repbonus to `reputation`, so I tried this:

```
$rep = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `reputation` = `reputation` + :rep WHERE `email` = :email");
$rep->bindParam(":email", $_SESSION['email']);
$rep->bindParam(":rep", $repbonus);
$rep->execute();
```

It doesn't work though, any pointers?

Comment: if it doesn't work then there is an error. Just make PDO report it, then read and fix

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted. It was a minor typo. Can you explain what you mean with make PDO report it, and how to?

Comment: It's explained in the answer linked at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, it seems I made a typo at first by saying bindParma instead of bindParam.